# Show that $E(XE[X|G])=E[(E[X|G)^2]$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I have a problem for my assignment which I dont know how to solve. can anyone please help me? Show that $E(XE[X|G])=E[(E[X|G)^2]$

Comment: What is $G$? A set, or a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: I have typeset your question. Please double-check that it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

First, think about how you would simulate XE(X|G). First, you could to select G from its marginal distribution, $f_G$ which would fix a value for E(X|G), then you would select X from the conditional density $f_{X|G}$. The expected value of XE(X|G) would be:

$\int\limits_G \int\limits_X f_G(g)E(X|G=g)xf_{X|G=g}(x)\;dxdg = \int\limits_G  f_G(g)E(X|G=g)\int\limits_Xxf_{X|G=g}(x)\;dxdg$ as the integrands are separable. The second integral (over X) is equal to E(X|G=g) and so the intgral simplifies to: $\int\limits_G f_G(g)(E(X|G=g))^2 dg = E[(E(X|G))^2]$

Answer (score 1):

In my answer I assume that $G$ is a random variable.

In general $E\left(X.f\left(G\right)\mid G\right)=f\left(G\right)E\left(X\mid G\right)$.
In special case $f\left(G\right)=E\left(X\mid G\right)$ this leads
to $E\left(X.E\left(X\mid G\right)\mid G\right)=E\left(X\mid G\right)^{2}$.
Taking the expectation on both sides gives $E\left(X.E\left(X\mid G\right)\right)=E\left(E\left(X\mid G\right)^{2}\right)$